# List all table names without knowing the database name within my machine

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am using SQl Server 2014, and Normally we can list out tables if we knew the DB name as :

```
USE YOURDBNAME
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

But I want to know all the tables **irrespective of db's** that are present on my machine

Or can I go for looping by listing out all DB name.(EXEC sp_databases)

Is there any better way to find out this?

Comment: `select * from information_schema.tables`?

Comment: @jarlh No man.. It just shows master DB tables . What I get with select count(*) from information_schema.tables = 6 where as select * from <anyDB>.information_schema.tables = 87. So this is not the Answer to list all the tables within my machine

Comment: SELECT sobjects.name
FROM sysobjects sobjects
WHERE sobjects.xtype = 'U'

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of getting all tables in your database

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM Sys.Tables
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

OR

```
SELECT sobjects.name FROM sysobjects sobjects WHERE sobjects.xtype = 'U'
```

[Docs for all the xtypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tab
```

or

```
select * from * cat
```

The first one will show the associated CLUSTERID with tables for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
```

and then you will need to create a cursor query (for your USE XXXX)  to iterate through the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```